# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Web Applications's [fifth moderator election](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Rubén]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! I'd also like to extend a huge thanks to [codingbadger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/5095/codingbadger) as he steps down after nine years as a moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4920809991700480/0).

Comment: Congratulations Rubén! Glad to finally see a new moderator in the team!

Comment: Thank you very much @Hydra

Comment: Congratulations Rubén. Thanks to both guys for stepping up.

Answer (score 5):

Congrats and welcome aboard, Ruben!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Good luck Rubén and regards.